# How to get the array key peer to peer?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is [my code](https://3v4l.org/Il55F):

```
<?php

$uriClass = 'dictionaries';
$uriMethod = 'quran';

$parent_of_table_code = array(11=>"islamic_sources",
                              12=>"islamic_sources",
                              65=>"dictionaries",
                              66=>"dictionaries");
$routes = array(11=>"quran",
                12=>"torat",
                65=>"quran",
                66=>"longman");

echo $table_code = array_search($uriMethod, $routes);

//=> 11
```

As you can see, the result is `11`, but **I need to get `65`**, because of the parent (`dictionaries`). `array_search()` returns the first match, I need to make it work according to the parent. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: just loop it use foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to first find all of the matches for one of the criteria (using `array_keys()` with the values to select) and then check each one with the other array to match the second value...

```
$matchedRoutes = array_keys($routes, $uriMethod);
foreach ( $matchedRoutes as $key )  {
    if ( $parent_of_table_code[$key] == $uriClass ) {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

There are other methods using purely array_ methods, but this just does the minimal checks.

**Update:**

You can reduce this to 1 loop and check everything without array methods at all...

```
foreach ( $routes as $key => $route )  {
    if ( $route == $uriMethod && $parent_of_table_code[$key] == $uriClass ) {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you simply echo $key without the if? (You've got the key in $matchedRoutes)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, the issue is that several of the `$routes` will match the 1 criteria (quran), the `if` then checks the second criteria (dictionaries) to ensure they both match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
$table_code = array_keys( 
   array_intersect_key( $routes, $parent_of_table_code ), 
$uriMethod );
```

`array_intersect_key` returns the keys of the two arrays `$routes` and `$parent_of_table_code` (that are same in both arrays). And from that `array_keys` gives you the result of keys with the `$uriMethod` as second argument (which returns the keys where $`uriMethod` matches).

**UPDATE**
$table_code would be an array so instead `$table_codes` would be a better name. You could iterate and echo out each key if you wanted to:

```
$table_codes = array_keys( 
   array_intersect_key( $routes, $parent_of_table_code ), 
$uriMethod );

foreach($table_codes as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does :-) You could just loop through the array and print out each item which would be the key :-)